# how to add ssl for subdomains in yii2 apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

https://www.example.com is my site which is ssl secured
https://x.example.com, https://y.example.com are my subdomains but its not getting secured.

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

I have already tried above code in my ssl vhost file but the error is still there

Comment: You need a wildcard certificate, it all depends what type of certificate you bought

Comment: I have wildcard ssl only

Comment: What error you have?

Comment: I purchased *.example.com as ssl certificate for all my subdomains but it error its showing SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.example.com, example.com